# Updating user profile details in meteor not working

Tags: meteor

How can I edit the user details in users collection in my meteor app.My code is

```
 Meteor.users.update({_id:this._id}, { $set:{"profile.name":pname}} )
```

This is working only for the 1st user in the list. How can I do this for all users listed ?

Comment: When you write it like that, there SHOULD be just one users on the list - `_id` is supposed to be different for different objects.

Comment: Your "this._id" probably isn't what you think it is.  Check that your UI is changing "this" appropriately.

Answer (score 14):

I found that the only way to update a Meteor user was to set the criteria using the _id with the `Meteor.userId()`:

```
Meteor.users.update( { _id: Meteor.userId() }, { $set: { 'oauth.token': token }} );
```

I do this on the server side so it will block the client until success/failure from Mongo.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that you are referencing something that doesn't exists

Replace:

`Meteor.users.update({_id:this._id}, { $set:{"profile.name":pname}} )`

by:

`Meteor.users.update({_id:this.userId}, { $set:{"profile.name":pname}} )`

Or Use Meteor.userId() as @occasl suggested before.

Just happened to me

Answer (score -2):

As per http://docs.meteor.com/#update, set the "multi" option to "true":

```
Meteor.users.update({_id:this._id}, { $set:{"profile.name":pname}}, {multi: true} )
```

Comment: While syntactically correct, the users collection cannot contain more than one user document sharing the same _id. If that is the case, then there is some far worse problem that needs attention.